# Dropping observations after Fuzzy Match

Tags: stata, matchit

I am doing some fuzzy matching using the 'matchit' command in Stata. After the fuzzy match, my data looks something like this

​

| Identifier | Variable B | Variable C | Similarity Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 0.4 |
| 1 | A | Y | 0.6 |
| 1 | A | Z | 1 |
| 1 | B | Y | 0.2 |
| 1 | B | X | 0.7 |
| 1 | B | Z | 0.8 |

For each unique Variable B, I want to keep the row with highest similarity score. However, I have an exception to make. If two unique observations in Variable B matches the best to the same entry in Variable C and one has similarity score of 1, then I want to keep the row with second highest similarity score. So, the final table should look like this:

​

| Identifier | Variable B | Variable C | Similarity Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Z | 1 |
| 1 | B | X | .7 |
|  |  |  |  |

Comment: Cross-posted on Reddit and receiving some attention there. https://www.reddit.com/user/Loud_Potential2099/submitted/  Please note: it is a rule on that Reddit and a good idea here to tell people about cross-posting.

Answer (score 0):

First, we find the rows with similarity score of 1. Call them perfect matches.

```
// Input example data
input Identifier str1 Variable_B str1 Variable_C Similarity_Score
               1             "A"             "X"              0.4
               1             "A"             "Y"              0.6
               1             "A"             "Z"                1
               1             "B"             "Y"              0.2
               1             "B"             "X"              0.7
               1             "B"             "Z"              0.8
end

// Find rows with a similarity score of 1
preserve
keep if Similarity_Score == 1
tempfile perfect_match
save "`perfect_match'", replace
```

`` "`perfect_match'" `` looks like:

| Identifier | Variable_B | Variable_C | Similarity_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Z | 1 |

Then we get all values of `Variable C` in those perfect matches.

```
// Find which `Variable C` has a similarity score of 1
keep Variable_C
duplicates drop
tempfile temp
save "`temp'", replace
```

`` "`temp'" `` looks like:

| Variable_C |
| --- |
| Z |

We don't want those values in `` "`temp'" `` to be matched with anything else, so drop them in the rawdata.

```
// Drop those `Variable C` above from the rawdata, so a perfectly matched
// `Variable C` will no longer be there
restore
merge m:1 Variable_C using "`temp'"
drop if _merge == 3
drop _merge
```

The remaining data look like:

| Identifier | Variable_B | Variable_C | Similarity_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | X | .7 |
| 1 | A | X | .4 |
| 1 | A | Y | .6 |
| 1 | B | Y | .2 |

In the rest of data, find the best match.

```
// Find the best match in the remaining data
gsort Variable_B -Similarity_Score
collapse (firstnm) Identifier Variable_C Similarity_Score, by(Variable_B)
```

Now the data looks like:

| Variable_B | Identifier | Variable_C | Similarity_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Y | .6 |
| B | 1 | X | .7 |

Please note that the current match for `Variable_B == "A"` is wrong! This is expected, as we've removed perfect matches in the first step. Now merge them back, and use them replace the wrong matches.

```
// Merge the perfect matches back into the data
merge 1:1 Variable_B using "`perfect_match'", replace update nogen
order Identifier Variable_B Variable_C Similarity_Score
sort Variable_B
```

Here is the final output:

| Identifier | Variable_B | Variable_C | Similarity_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Z | 1 |
| 1 | B | X | .7 |